# using facebook api for searching

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

```
i want to use facebook api by python to make search on name , like this :

import webapp2
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(long_access_token)
search = graph.request('/search?q=alajwadi&type=user')

lass MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    for ids in search["data"]:    
            self.response.out.write(ids["name"])
            self.response.out.write('<br />')
```

when i run this in launcher of google app engine , i got this error :

raise GraphAPIError(response)
GraphAPIError: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

whats the problem ?

Comment: The error usually means You're not providing an access token to authenticate your request to the API - Are you sure the token is valid and is definitely being included with your request to the API?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass an User Access Token. This is necessary, as outlined in the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

> The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.
>
> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

Comment: thanks  Tobi, i pass the variable (long_access_token) in the begining like : long_access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx.......... , the same error